# Why does the definition of the oracle in Deutsch's algorithm fail to specify its action on superpositions?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

[image: Deutsch Algorithm Circuit]

I’m trying to understand the Deutsch algorithm. I can see that the math shows the algorithm to be correct, but I don’t understand how the math represents the given conditions.

The oracle is supposed to accept an input of 0 or 1 and output a value of 0 or 1. So what does it mean to pass a qubit in super position? I don’t see how this is defined, and so I don’t see how this algorithm can claim to test both input states at once. In my world, this is an invalid input and not defined by the function and that’s that - like 10/0. I guess the quantum world is a bit different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Oracle's action on computational basis

The oracle's action is defined by the equation
$$
U_f|x\rangle|y\rangle = |x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle\tag1
$$
where $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ and $y\in\{0,1\}$ are bitstrings of lengths $n$ and $1$, respectively, so that $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ are computational basis states.

### Misconception

The question appears to be based on incorrect interpretation of $(1)$ as defining $U_f$ by specifying its action on every input in its domain. If this were true, then $U_f$ would be a function defined on computational basis states only. Consequently, every other state, i.e. every non-trivial superposition of computational basis states, would lie outside of $U_f$'s domain and hence constitute invalid input.

### Extension by linearity

However, this interpretation is incorrect. In quantum computing, as in linear algebra more generally, linear functions, including quantum operations, are often defined by specifying their action on a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) and then [*extending by linearity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Linear_extensions).

Consider a linear function $f:V\to W$ from vector space $V$ to vector space $W$ over some field of scalars $\mathbb{K}$. Linearity means that $f$ satisfies two conditions
$$
\begin{align}
f(x+y)&=f(x)+f(y)\tag2\\
f(ax)&=af(x)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
where $x,y\in V$ and $a\in\mathbb{K}$.

A straightforward, but very important consequence of linearity is that every set of equations $f(x_i)=y_i$ with $x_i$ ranging over a basis of $V$ *completely defines* $f$ in the sense that there is one and only one$^1$ function that satisfies $f(x_i)=y_i$.

This allows us to be parsimonious in specifying the action of $f$ on its input: it is sufficient to specify the action on any basis of the input vector space. This is very convenient because a basis is typically much smaller than the input space (in quantum computing the basis is typically finite, but the input space is uncountably infinite) and because a basis can often be chosen to be very simple (e.g. one can choose a basis without entangled states).

### Example

Consider for example the CNOT gate defined as
$$
\text{CNOT}|x\rangle|y\rangle = |x\rangle|x\oplus y\rangle\tag4
$$
where $x,y\in\{0,1\}$ and $\oplus$ denotes addition modulo $2$. Equation $(4)$ specifies the action of CNOT on the computational basis. Let's try to exploit the fact that CNOT must be linear$^2$, i.e. that it must satisfy $(2)$ and $(3)$, to infer its action on some other input not covered by the specification $(4)$ such as $|+\rangle|-\rangle$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\text{CNOT}|+\rangle|-\rangle&=\text{CNOT}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)\tag5\\
&=\frac12\text{CNOT}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)\tag6\\
&=\frac12\text{CNOT}(|00\rangle-|01\rangle+|10\rangle-|11\rangle)\tag7\\
&=\frac12(\text{CNOT}|00\rangle-\text{CNOT}|01\rangle+\text{CNOT}|10\rangle-\text{CNOT}|11\rangle)\tag8\\
&=\frac12(|00\rangle-|01\rangle+|11\rangle-|10\rangle)\tag9\\
&=|-\rangle|-\rangle\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
where we used the definition of $|\pm\rangle$ states, equation $(3)$, distributivity of the tensor product over addition, equation $(2)$, specification of the action of CNOT on the computational basis states given by equation $(4)$, and finally the definition of $|\pm\rangle$ states once more.

---

<sup>$^1$ This is related to another convenient way of specifying linear functions: matrices.

$^2$ By the postulates of quantum mechanics.</sup>